# How to filter JSON data in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to populate data on the page however, it's not getting rendered on the page. Instead its throwing an error msg:

> core.es5.js:1020 ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 322

**question-card.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RetrieveDataService } from '../retrieve-data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-question-card',
  templateUrl: './question-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./question-card.component.css']
})
export class QuestionCardComponent implements OnInit {
 question = '';
 questions = [];
  constructor(private retrieveDataService: RetrieveDataService) {
    this.appendContent();  
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  appendContent(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      this.retrieveDataService.fetchData().subscribe(data=>{
            if (data[i].type == "question-card") {
                this.question = (data[i].question);
                this.questions.push(this.question);
            }
       });  
    }
  }
}
```

**question-card.component.html**

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let question of questions">
<h3>{{question.section}}</h3>
</div>
```

**retrieve-data.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()

export class RetrieveDataService {
  constructor(private http: Http) { 
  }
  fetchData(){
      return this.http.get('assets/page-content.json').map(
        (response) => response.json()
      )
  }
}
```

**Page-content.json**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "question-card",
        "section": "some text comes here...",
        "headline": "some text comes here...",
        "question": "some text comes here...?",
        "options": ['<25%', '25-50%', '51-75%', '>75%'],
        "notes": "some text comes here..."
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "type": "question-flipping-card",
        "section": "some text comes here...",
        "headline": "some text comes here...",
        "options": ['<25%', '25-50%', '51-75%', '>75%']
    }
]
```

Comment: use " instead of ' in the JSON.

Comment: Your `i` inside the for loop will always be 4 in your subscribe callback. And since your json does not have a `data[4]` right now it will be undefined.

Comment: @echonax Could you please explain further along with example?

Comment: @RahulDagli if you are using `subscribe` then this is an async operation. Async operations take time to complete. Let's say 100ms for sake of simplicity for this example. When `i=0` you fire this request and it will take 100ms for the code to fall into the subscribe block. When it does indeed fall into the subscribe block(after 100ms) your for loop would already have been completed. Because in 100ms a for loop can traverse maybe even the safe max integer value. Hence for all of the 5 `fetchData` requests your `i` will be the max value in the for loop. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/dyyad3nd/

Comment: @echonax, Thanks for the explanation. So what's the prefered way to loop inside Async operation instead of `for` loop?

Comment: You are not looping inside the async operation you are looping outside of it. I don't think this is a good pattern. I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the length of your json you can use `let` instead of `var`. `let` will preserve the `i` for that block scoped async operation. If you use `var`, then `i` will be the last value for all of your async operations:

```
appendContent(){
  this.retrieveDataService.fetchData().subscribe(data=>{
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i].type == "question-card") {
                this.questioncard = data[i];
                this.questionscard.push(this.questioncard);
            }
        } 
   });  

 }

}
```

**html:**

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let q of questionscard">
   <h3>{{q?.section}}</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: After updating it to this. When I do `console.log(this.questions);` it outputs empty array?

Comment: @RahulDagli please be more specific :-) where are you doing `console.log(this.questions);`?

Comment: Below `for(){...}`

Comment: @RahulDagli I don't think you know how async operations work in javascript. I already told you that async operations take like 100ms~ time to complete. By the time `fetchData` completes its work your `console.log` will already be printed. Write your `console.log` inside the `subscribe` callback. I will update my answer.

Comment: Yes that worked. Now my last query is that the data is not rendering on the page.

Comment: @RahulDagli try changing your html like I've done in my answer. Don't use `question of questions` you are also using `this.question` in your component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149118/discussion-between-rahul-dagli-and-echonax).

Answer (score 1):

## updated

first thing first, you actually calls service many times. `map` and `subscribe` already iterate through response data, you don't need that for loop.

secondly, Angular will not updates HTML after Array mutation (`Array.push` or `shift`) you can either..

1. set new value like this

   `this.questions = [...this.questions, this.question]`
2. or use [Observable](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/using_observables.html) pattern

try this

```
  appendContent() {
    this.retrieveDataService.fetchData() 
      .filter((item) => item.type === 'question-card') 
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.questions = [...this.questions, data]
      });
  }
```

read more [sample here](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/observables_array_operations.html)

---

### original answer

in your json file.

```
{
 // .. 
 "options": ['<25%', '25-50%', '51-75%', '>75%'],
}
```

single quote `'` is not valid JSON format

replace `'` with `"`

---

from [www.json.org](http://www.json.org/)

> A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be nested.

Comment: Do you have a source for this answer?

Comment: Thanks, that error msg is gone but now I'm getting another error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined`

Comment: the `appendContent` function has hard coded for loop 5 times but your json data.length is 2 that cause data[i] to be undefined when index out of range

Comment: If I change the value `i` to `1` the error is gone but still the data is not getting rendered on the page?